# Integration problems concerned with Gateway Hosted account type in PayPoint.net

Tags: asp.net

I have set up a Gateway Hosted account at PayPoint.net. I want to customise the form where users fill card's information and where it displays error messages such as'invalid card' before going to bank for checking. Is that possible? Can I use Gateway Hosted account alone without Gateway Freedom? What are the disadvantages?

Comment: Gateway Hosted account is a very limited one. Account's users cannot customise the given templates at all. But the paradox is that some features that are available only to Gateway Freedom account are somehow available to Gateway Hosted account such as 'template' and 'err_template' parameters.